# MVC2 referencing external JavaScript file from Master Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the correct way to absolute reference an external JavaScript file from the Site.Master file. In Web Forms I used to do it like this src="<%#ResolveUrl(@"Scripts/Common.js") %>".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Content` URL helper

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [MVC2 futures assembly](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) you can make use of the `Html.Script(string, [string]);` method.

```
<%=Html.Script("/path/to/release/file.js", "path/to/debug/file.js")%>
```

The second string parameter is optional and allows you to specify a different file to be included when running the project in a Debug configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a helper class for this, you can modify it to suit a script reference outside of your site;

```
public static string JavaScript(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
{
    return helper.Content(String.Format("~/Scripts/{0}", fileName));
}
```

Then in the master page;

```
<script src="<%=Url.JavaScript("jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Although the futures assembly approach is probably the better way to go now, I like the helper class because it can hold other methods in there that let you find your way to images, css and ClientBin etc...